# Multiple logs files with muptiples levels automatically

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I've searched online for a solution and haven't found anything.

My problem is:

Have a game with lot of rooms. There's a chatroom inside of every room. I need to create a LOG of those rooms in different files with LOG4J.

I don't want to create an appender for every room that have been created. I need a automatically way to create a log file per room.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Log4J can create different log files for different classes using nothing but the log4j configuration file. If the rooms are instances of one or more classes, you'll have to handle it through your code.  One possibility is to create a logger in the constructor and point it to a unique temp file so that each room that is constructed gets its own log file. I do not know how you make it easy to identify a room with a file other than forcing output as the first line. That might work but would still make it hard to identify the correct file just by the name.  If the rooms have something unique about them you could try to use that as the log file name but without code from you I'd be guessing how you could do that.